# Unbind F5 key from laser pointer

Tags: key-bindings

I've got a presentation pointer (Kensington Wireless Presenter), and as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/110) issue (that is for the rest unrelated, but it is the only mention of the same problem I could find), the back and forward keys work properly, but when I press the laser pointer key, along with turning on the laser, the receiver interprets this as a key press of the F5 button, which is rather annoying since this also triggers the going in or out of presentation mode.

I'm on Windows, and I'm curious whether there is a way to bind the laser key on my pointer to another button (or none at all) on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is software like KeyTweak to rebind keys overall. Problem is, that you would rebind F5 but that might be a temporary solution until you find a better one